# Wordpress new-user registration e-mail not sent out when registering with Wordpress-Social-Login

Tags: email, wordpress, registration

As the title suggests, our Wordpress site will correctly trigger the 'Activation', then 'Welcome' e-mail workflow to users that signup via the the non-WSL (Wordpress Social Login) route.  Users that signup via WSL do not trigger the 'Welcome' e-mail, which is a problem.

To be honest, my best guess is that perhaps it has to do something with a non-WSL user trigger the chain of events that starts with a user 'activating' their account, which then fires off the subsequent e-mails.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit 1:  E-mails are customised user Profile Builder Pro.

Comment: We're using Wordpress SL not WooThemes SL.

Comment: Can you provide a link that that plugin? Someone could likely review the code quickly and see if / why no email is being triggered.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-social-login/

Also see edit 1, if that affects anything.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you reduce the potential issues by removing the Profile Builder Pro plugin first and seeing if that resolves the issue?

Comment: Hi @cale_b.  It turns out that PB and WSL have no knowledge of each other and that the PB form (obviously...doh!) only triggers the PB user customised e-mails.  The PB guys are also developing their own social widget addon.